# Issue with Inner Join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

Im trying to join 3 tables together using inner joins, but the results are showing more records than what should be there. My Data tables are set up like this:

```
Table:gameday.atbats

   GameName                     Inning num  b   s   o   Batter   Pitcher      Result
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1   1   2   3   1   457803  150116  Jay Bruce strikes out swinging.  
    gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1   2   1   0   2   433898  150116  Jeff Keppinger lines out to right fielder Hunter Pence.  
    gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1   3   3   1   2   458015  150116  Joey Votto singles on a line drive to right fielder Hunter Pence.  
    gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1   4   2   3   3   429665  150116  Edwin Encarnacion called out on strikes.  
    gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1   5   1   2   0   430565  459371  Kazuo Matsui singles on a line drive to right fielder Jay Bruce.  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Table: Gameday.pitches
 GameName                   GameAtBatID      Result
------------------------------------------------------
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Called Strike
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Ball
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Swinging Strike
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Ball
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Foul
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Foul
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Swinging Strike
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  2       Ball
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  2       In play, out(s)
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  3       Called Strike
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  3       Ball
--------------------------------------------------------

Table:batters
   GameName                     id         name_display_first_last
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  407783      Geoff Geary
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  209315      David Newhan
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  115629      LaTroy Hawkins
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  113889      Darin Erstad
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  457803      Jay Bruce
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  433898      Jeff Keppinger
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  458015      Joey Votto
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  429665      Edwin Encarnacion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm running what seems like a fairly standard set of inner joins, connecting each of the various tables together to get a output that shows me pitch by pitch what each batter did throughout the game. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT 


    gameday.atbats.inning,
    gameday.batters.name_display_first_last,
    gameday.pitches.Result
FROM
 gameday.atbats
        Inner join 
     gameday.pitches on gameday.atbats.num = gameday.pitches.gameAtBatID
        inner join
    gameday.batters on gameday.atbats.batter = gameday.batters.ID

    where gameday.atbats.gamename = "gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1"
```

My issue is that when I run this query, batters are having more results than they should. For example, in the first inning Batter jay Bruce (num 1 in the atbats table) should have 7 pitches thrown to him in the first inning, but when I run the query he will have 10 pitches thrown to him. What Am I doing incorrectly to get these results. Also, I am aware that these field names are named horribly, but they were named by someone else, and I have not had a chance to change them yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting that `atbats.num` and `pitches.GameAtBatID` are not meant to *globally* uniquely identify an at-bat, but rather, that they only uniquely identify an at-bat *within* a given game. So in addition to restricting `atbats.GameName` to the desired game, you also need to specify that `pitches.GameName = atbats.GameName`:

```
SELECT gameday.atbats.inning,
       gameday.batters.name_display_first_last,
       gameday.pitches.Result
  FROM gameday.atbats
  JOIN gameday.pitches
    ON gameday.atbats.GameName = gameday.pitches.GameName
   AND gameday.atbats.num = gameday.pitches.GameAtBatID
  JOIN batters
    ON gameday.atbats.GameName = gameday.batters.GameName
   AND gameday.atbats.batter = gameday.batters.ID
 WHERE gameday.atbats.gamename = 'gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1'
```

(Note: I also included the analogous `AND` for `batters`, because although the values of `batters.ID` are large enough that it seems plausible that that really *is* a unique field, it made sense to include it for consistency.)

Answer (score 1):

That is true, because SQL work from TOP to buttom so when you join first two table you will have have

```
Inner join 
     gameday.pitches on gameday.atbats.num = gameday.pitches.gameAtBatID
```

you will have these results

```
GameName                   GameAtBatID      Result         Batter    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Called Strike      457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Ball               457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Swinging Strike    457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Ball               457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Foul               457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Foul               457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  1       Swinging Strike    457803 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  2       Ball               433898
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  2       In play, out(s)    433898
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  3       Called Strike      458015 
gid_2008_09_24_cinmlb_houmlb_1  3       Ball               458015
```

then when you add new line of join that is

```
inner join
    gameday.batters on gameday.atbats.batter = gameday.batters.ID
```

you will have these result from three table

```
name_display_first_last   GameAtBatID      Result          Batter    
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Jay Bruce                1       Called Strike      457803 
    Jay Bruce                1       Ball               457803 
    Jay Bruce                1       Swinging Strike    457803 
    Jay Bruce                1       Ball               457803 
    Jay Bruce                1       Foul               457803 
    Jay Bruce                1       Foul               457803 
    Jay Bruce                1       Swinging Strike    457803 
    Jeff Keppinger           2       Ball               433898
    Jeff Keppinger           2       In play, out(s)    433898
    David Newhan             3       Called Strike      458015 
    David Newhan             3       Ball               458015
```